# jQuery library for CodeIgniter from Google with not enough instructions

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, google-code

I loaded this jQuery library from http://code.google.com/p/codeigniter-jquery/ which has proven to work the best out of the existing jQuery libraries, since they don't give error's until I try to use any jQuery methods.

Basically I've gotten this new script to load jQuery, and create temporary js files, but I can't find any documentation in how to get this work.

I've tried `$this->jquery->hide('#blog0')` but it just throws an error. I'm pretty sure this library was made for pre 2.0 CI, but I don't know if that would keep it from working still.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the library was made for pre-2.0 CodeIgniter, I wouldn't use it. Instead, I would suggest using the Javascript library built in to CodeIgniter. See the instructions here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html.

Also, bear in mind that only a small set of available features are usable from CodeIgniter/PHP on the server side. You may be better off learning to use jQuery by itself. For instance, here's how to hide a div after clicking a link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() { // this function prevents code from running until page loads

    $("#your_link_id").click( // this attaches the event handler

         function() {
             $("#your_div_id").hide(); // hides your div when link is clicked
         }
    );
});

</script>
```

Put it in your view files (either the head or the body is fine), update your id's, and you're good to go!

Comment: I understand how to use jquery on it's own perfectly, but there are cases where I need to pass php data through a jquery event, and combining both of them in the view file is very cumbersome, because to echo all the php data to a javascript variable adds up and pollutes the html file. Additionally the CodeIgniter library is faulty, otherwise I wouldn't be looking for a solution.